# Getting 'undefined' after end of scope

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using firebase auth and when a user logs it, I'm trying to get his uid (key) and save it.

This is my code (Here `console.log(that.uid);` returns the key):

```
 loginWithEmail(email, password) 
  {
    // Resolving scope problems in TypeScript
    let that = this;

    return this.af.auth.login(
    {
      email: email,
      password: password
    },
    {
      provider: AuthProviders.Password,
      method: AuthMethods.Password,
    }).then((user) => 
      {
        that.uid = user.uid;
       // console.log(that.uid);
      })
  }
```

and I have a function that gets called from another component that returns the uid:

```
getUid()
  {
    console.log(this.uid);
    return this.uid;
  }
```

Here `console.log(this.uid);` returns `'undefined'`.

Why does it happen and how can I resolve it?

**EDIT:**

I was read the answers below and understand that the problem is with async.. but I didn't find a solution how to save my data (in this example: user id) from async function to sync one.

I will be glad if someone can offer a solution to my code so I will be able to understand how to fix it and to use well async and sync.

**EDIT2:**

getUid() function is provide inside afservice whith the loginWithEmail(email, password) function.
getUid() was called from another component, in my case HomeComponent in this way:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit 
{

   permission: number;

  constructor(private afService: AF, private router: Router) 
  { 
            console.log(afService.getUid());
  }
}
```

thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Where is `getUid()` defined? Can you provide more details about this

Comment: I was edited my question, thanks